# Как правильно реализовать метод .on(), похожий на $(...).on в jQuery?

Tags: javascript

Выдает ошибку *$(...).on is not a function*

Как правильно реализовать и исправить этот код?

```js
$ = (s) => window.document.querySelector(s)
function on(event, callback){
    return addEventListener(event, callback);
}
$('div').on('click',function(){
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<div>click 1</div>
<div>click 2</div>
```

Comment: версия jQuery какая?

Comment: @ioprst, здесь нет jquery

Comment: действительно, не заметил определение функции, пардон

Comment: `querySelector` вернет элемент, разве он имеет метод `on`? Вы же вызываете метод `on` элемента, а не собственную функцию.

Comment: Во-первых - метод on не включен в элемент. Во-вторых - addEventListener вешается на определенный элемент

Comment: @ioprst, я понимаю, но как можно изменить код и достичь нужного результата?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ = (s) => {
    const el = window.document.querySelector(s);
    const self = {
        on: (event, callback) => {
            el.addEventListener(event, callback);
            // Для вызова по цепочке как в jQuery
            return self;
        },
    };
    // Возвращаем объект, содержащий метод `on`
    return self;
}

$('div').on('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

**UPD**

```
$ = (s) => {
    const el = window.document.querySelector(s);
    el.on = (event, callback) => {
        el.addEventListener(event, callback);
        // Для вызова по цепочке как в jQuery
        return el;
    };
    // Возвращаем элемент, содержащий метод `on`
    return el;
}

$('div').on('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: А как можно вернуть `el`? Если к примеру вызывать другие методы, например `$('div').classList.add('show');` внутри там где `console.log(e);`

Comment: @Squeli47, дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает! только маленькую опечатку `},` заменить на `}`

Comment: @Squeli47, поправил

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение:

```js
window.$ = function(selector) {
  if (selector === document) {
    return new jQueryWrap([document]);  
  }
  
  /***/ 
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);  
  return new jQueryWrap(elems);
}

/***/
function jQueryWrap(elems) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    this[i] = elems[i];
  }
  
  this.length = elems.length;
}

jQueryWrap.prototype.on = function(event, target, fn) {
  // Если все аргументы на месте - запускаем делегирование:

  if (arguments.length == 3) {
    this._delegate(event, target, fn);
    return this;
  }

  // Иначе, считаем, что второй аргумент - функция.
  fn = target;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    this[i].addEventListener(event, fn);
  }
  
  return this;
};

jQueryWrap.prototype._delegate = function(event, selector, fn) {

  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    this[i].addEventListener(event, delegator);
  }
  
  function delegator(e) {
    if (e.target.closest(selector)) fn.call(e.target, e);
  }
  
};

/***/
$('div').on('click', function(){
  console.log(this.textContent);
});

$(document).on('click', '.x', function(){
  console.log(this.className);
});
```

```html
<div class="x a">click 1</div>
<div class="x b">click 2</div>
```

Справки:

- [Оператор new](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)
- [Ключевое слово «this»](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)
- [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)